# Calculating with times in a database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a database with colums `[id, Boat, Stop, Time_D]` in which `Boat` is type of boat, `Stop` is number of the stop, and `Time_D` is departure time of the boat. 
So far all went very smooth with the database, I inserted a couple of sample times and boats for stop 1.

But I now want to use those times to insert the times for stop 2, given that the difference of `Time_D 
(stop1)` and `Time_D (stop2)` is 10 minutes.

I don't of course want to have to manually type the (lots of) departure times of stop 1 again, and I think I can do that smarter.

Those new times can go in the same table, below the times of stop 1, or in a seperate table (then I don't need the column `stop` anymore of course), I don't really care how it works.

Until now I worked with MySQLi and PHP, I hope that will work for this too.

Comment: inter-row calculations in mysql can be pretty painful. do it in client-side php code.

Comment: ^Can't agree more, php it up man.

Comment: @Marc B Ok, so I'd put it in an array, and then add the 10 minutes, and then put it back in somehow?

Comment: pretty much. `select * from yourtable` into an array, do `$row[$i+1]['time_d'] = $row[$i]['time_d'] + $time_difference`, or whatever the calculation should be, then iterate the array and update the db with the changed values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. When I don't succeed I'll come back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, see comments in the code.

```
$time_difference=600; //time difference in departure times between the two stops
$stop_old = "1"; //stop from which to use the times to calculate the next times
$stop_new = "2"; //the new stop


//get times from stop in array
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `Boat`, `Time_D` from `Schedule` where `Stop` = '".$stop_old."' ");
//get database result
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {                         
$rows[] = $row['Time_D']; //store all the times in one array
$boats[] = $row['Boat']; // store all the boats in one array
}
//print_r ($rows); //used for debugging
//Iterate over the array to change all the elements
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($rows); $i++){
$rows[$i] = ( strtotime($rows[$i]) ) + ($time_difference); //with timestamps, because, well, php and times...
$rows[$i] = date('H:i:s', ($rows[$i]) ); // back from timestamp to time
}
//print_r($rows);
//print_r($boats);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($rows); $i++){
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `Schedule`(`Boat`, `stop`, `Time_D`) VALUES ('$boats[$i]', '".$stop_new."', '$rows[$i]')");
}
```